# OpenLayers 3: Vector Layer loses styling when map pans or changes zoom

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm working on switching from OpenLayers 2 to OpenLayers 3 and supplementing my reading of The Book of OpenLayers 3 by trying some things out on my own. There's a project that I'm building [here](http://www.tandooriallstars.com/tom/index.php) that should be fairly simple: take form inputs and use them as parameters for building a vector layer. The interface works as intended, save for one problem.

Whenever I pan the map or zoom it, the vector layer seems to disappear. I can't for the life of me imagine what's going on. Anyone able to help me figure out what I can do to keep the layer in place?

To make things easier, I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dheerajchand/pb46g5h5/), please feel free to use at will.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. You might be better off putting the code on jsFiddle or similar and producing a minimal example demonstrating the problem. At the moment that is a lot of code to read through.

Comment: Hi! I linked to the project inline, added the code as a courtesy for those who didn't want to click through. If that is not in accordance with GIS.SE custom, I'll be happy to remove it!

Comment: The reason that jsFiddle and the like is preferable, is because you can see the output and code side by side, and someone can update with a fix and post that. It is now possible to see your issue, but harder to see the code.

Comment: Point taken! Sorry, I am new to SE, generally, still getting my sea legs. I'll edit to include a JSFiddle link.

Comment: Perfect. I wish everyone found their sea legs this quickly :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in line 77 [here](https://gitlab.com/dheeraj-chand/ol3prototype/blob/84d754e074e334177c876a6b435187e3f4a4b090/mapit.js). It turns out that for whatever reason, I misunderstood falsiness in JavaScript and my style-builder function was erring on undefined styles. Who knew? The rest of the code works, though!!!